# Massively large number of packets dropped by interface

Tags: debian, vmware-esxi, linux-networking, tcpdump, vyatta

I have a virtual machine on ESXi 5 acting as a firewall for a PBX, it is running vyatta. When I run tcpdump on any interface, I get some ridiculous numbers! e.g.

```
4 packets captured
402 packets received by filter
210 packets dropped by kernel
4294966860 packets dropped by interface
```

This was from approx 3 seconds of tcpdump. This occurs intermittently on the 2 external (i.e. cable modem) interfaces, and rarely on the lan interface. This tends to coincide with dropped packets, but as the site is remote it is difficult to see exactly what's happening during down times. After a reboot, it doesnt normally happen again for at least a week. 
Any suggestions for where to look?

Running vyatta Core 6.5 R1, which is based on Debian squeeze (6.0.5).

Comment: Details? What kind of host? What kind of NICs? What kind of vNICs? What Linux NIC driver? What kernel version? What firmware version (both for the host and the NICs)? What version of ESXi?